# Group Grid Row Wise

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, grouping, extjs4.1

I have a grid, that displays the values in column form. but I want it to be displayed as rows; as shown in the image below:

[image]

My code is as follows. Presently I can see the data in Column wise, and not Row wise (Grouped one under the other) as shown in the image. How can I group the components Row wise?

```
initComponent: function() {
            var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
                groupHeaderTpl: 'Group: {name} ({rows.length})', /
                startCollapsed: true          
            });
            this.columns = [
            { text: "Name", dataIndex: 'f_name' },
    ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also to add this to your store definition:

```
...
groupField: 'f_topic' // or whatever your field name is 
...
```